# How to prove $2n+1$ is odd for $n \in N$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Usually, it seems that if $x\in N$, then "$x$ is *odd*" is translated *by definition* as $\exists y\in N: x=2 y+1$, but can we prove this?

Given:

1. $\forall a\in N:[Even(a)\iff \exists b\in N: a=2 b]$
2. $\forall a:[Odd(a)\iff \neg Even(a)]$

Can we actually prove: $\forall a\in N: Odd(2a+1)$

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

**Follow-up**

Thanks all for your suggestions. Using them, I was finally able to formally prove the above. See Corollary at https://dcproof.com/EvenNextOdd.htm (127 lines, not for the faint of heart!)

Comment: [well-ordering](https://brilliant.org/wiki/the-well-ordering-principle/#:~:text=The%20well%2Dordering%20principle%20says,integers%20has%20a%20least%20element.) may be helpful

Comment: There is a difference between showing that $2a+1$ is always odd, and showing that any odd number can be written as $2a+1$. I think you actually want the latter (or rather, you want _both_), but at the moment you're asking for the former, and that's the answer you've gotten below.

Comment: If $0 \in \Bbb{N}$, then your definition is okay.  However if $0 \not\in \Bbb{N}$, then your definition is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So according to your given definitions, we can say that;

> $x$ is an even number if there exists $y$ such that $x=2y$

> $y$ is an even number if there doesn't exist $y$ such that $x=2y$

Now, we can see that given any positive integer, either there exists such a $y$ so that $x=2y,$ or there doesn't exist any such $y.$ So any positive integer is either odd or even, and each positive integer that is not even is always odd, and vice versa.

So consider a number $x=2y+1.$ We claim that it can't be even. Suppose for contradiction that it is even. Then we have that $x=2y+1=2z$ for some $z.$ But then;
\begin{align*}
&2y+1=2z\\
\implies & 2y-2z=1\\
\implies & 2(y-z)=1.
\end{align*}

This implies that $2\mid 1,$ which is not true. So every number of the form $2y+1$ has to be odd. Now, let $x$ be an odd number. Consider the set $S=\{x,x-2,x-4,x-6,\cdots\}.$ We know by the Well Ordering Principle, that there is a least positive integer in this set.

This least positive integer is of the form $x-2y$ for some $y.$ Now, we know that it can't be $2,$ because then;
\begin{align*}
& x-2y=2\\
\implies & x=2y+2=2(y+1)=\text{Even.}
\end{align*}

It can also not be greater than $2$ otherwise, because then;
\begin{align*}
& x-2y>2\\
\implies & x-2(y-1)>0\text{ }\text{ is an even smaller positive element of }S
\end{align*}

Hence, the number $x-2y$ which is the least positive element of $S$ has to be equal to $1.$ So we have;
\begin{align*}
& x-2y=1\\
\implies & x=2y+1.
\end{align*}

We have proved that if $x$ is an odd number then it is of the form $2y+1,$ and if it is of the form $2y+1,$ then it is an odd number. So we are done.

Answer (score 0):

Just from the Peano axioms you can prove:

$$\forall x (\exists y \ x = y + y \lor \exists y \ x = s(y+y))$$

(you'll have to use the inductive axiom to do so)

Once you have that, you can derive any one of the following three statements from the other two:

$$\forall x (Even(x) \leftrightarrow \exists y \ x = y + y)$$

$$\forall x (Odd(x) \leftrightarrow \exists y \ x = s(y + y))$$

$$\forall x (Odd(x) \leftrightarrow \neg Even(x))$$